# How to run a yaml config file?

Tags: security, syntax-error, computer-science, helper, feature-engineering

I'm running "wpdistillery/config.yml" and getting the error message

> zsh: permission denied

Comment: You can't run a yml file.

Answer (score 0):

YAML files are typical configuration files, you can open and edit them with a texteditor of your choice (such as vim, nano or ee and many more) but you can't run them like a bash script.
WPdistillery then access it and sets the configuration for Wordpress accordingly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).